# how to communicate a contact to keep me in mind for better opportunities?

Tags: communication

To keep it short and to the point, my dad knows a few people working in the IT industry. My dad has done some construction work in their premises. That's how my dad gets to know these individuals meet each other.

My dad has spoken to them individually about me, as I work in IT, and many have given him their email addresses. My dad wants me to contact them.

I have some doubts:

1. I am not entirely sure what my dad has discussed with them
   individually. He tends to forget details so I cannot ask him.
2. I have not met them personally nor been in contact with them.

**The question is:**

**How do I contact these individuals in the best way possible without sounding in my email like I am "begging for a job"? Also, since this email will be my first form of contact, I want to ensure I make a positive impression.
What would you suggest that I write in the mail so it sounds both professional and casual? These individuals are consultants.**

*The primary goal is to email my CV to these individuals my CV for career possibilities, and if they have vacancies for a better job than the one I currently have, then apply for that job through these individuals.*

Also, how would you suggest that I "follow this up"? I mean, reminding them of me for a "better opportunity".

I don't know if I am making all of this slightly too complicated, however in a way, I want to ensure that I make a good impression.

Thanks!

Comment: "I dad wants me to contact them" "What would you suggest me to write in the mail so it sounds both proffessional and casual?" "career posibilities" [further examples elided] I would suggest English with proper grammar and spelling.

Comment: English is not my first language.

Comment: No excuses. First, there are online dictionaries all over. Second, the input text boxes on this site include a spell checker. Third, I don't get a break for English being my fourth language either. Fourth, if you do a slop job on your spelling/grammar in your resume and cover letter, I, as the recipient of your communication, will presume that you'll do a slop job on the tasks that are assigned to you. Nobody is paying you so that they can chase after you to make sure that your tasks were done right.

Comment: Quibble, @VietnhiPhuvan: "sloppy job" is the more common idiom. (Learning never ends -- but I agree; people will assume that what you show them reflects your best efforts, and potential employers will judge you partly by that. If in doubt, get a friend to proofread. Many of us do that even though we're native speakers; *anyone's* writing can be improved.)

Comment: You send them a resume and on that resume you are currently employed.  They will figure out are looking for a better job.

Answer (score 8):

"I am following up on [state your dad's name] who is my dad and who has told me that he has recently discussed with you the matter of my interest in employment with your firm.

To this end, I am attaching my resume for your review.

Thanks

[Your signature]
"

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you're going to be writing the letters in English, one thing you should do is ensure that your English is perfect. (If your letters are going to be in something other than English, it's probably worth clarifying your question to explain your location). At the moment, your question is pretty much full of spelling and grammar errors; three glaring examples:

- "I dad wants me to contact them" (should be "My dad")
- "both proffessional and casual" (should be "professional")
- "career posibilities" (should be "possibilities")

I appreciate that English isn't your first language, but there are plenty of resources out there to help you - there's no excuse at all for not using a spellchecker (it's really hard for be to hit "Post your answer" on this post with those bits of red underlining in it), and I'm sure you can get a friend / colleague / someone else who does have English as a native language to proof read it for you.

Why does this matter? Because it's an indication of the care you're putting into the task - if you're not going to make a small amount of effort towards making your initial contact with a potential employer look professional, people are rightly or wrongly going to draw conclusions about the amount of effort and care you'll put into doing the actual job. First impressions *do* count.